# Settings, App and Messages Backup AND restore of non-rooted Android 6+ devices?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, backup

I need to send in my phone for a repair. The phone still works normally, so I like to backup all my phone specific data (SMS, whatsApp messages, app settings, account settings (contacts and calender sync), ...) and wipe the phone before I send it in.

I read [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices) - but the question is basically from back in 2012 - and so is the most upvoted answer (`adb`) which also disclaims *"This solution will not back up and restore contact, SMS or calendar information"* which makes it seem rather half-baked to me. (sorry.)

Also, Android 6 has a [built-in backup](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2015/10/android-6-0s-auto-backup-for-apps-perfect-data-backup-for-the-1-5), I'm just totally unsure how well that works. (And what app stuff it does or doesn't backup.)

```
settings > backup&restore > more > manual backup > (sdcard)
```

Here's what the backup (to SD card) confirmation looks like: (sorry German)

[image: Backup Confirmation from Sony Z3 compact]

- So what did it actually backup (seems like SMS are included / bullet Gespräche") and how can I verify that?
- How do I check whether some app settings are included or not?
- Can I be confident to get that stuff restored to the factory reset device once it is returned from repair?

Android Version is shown as 6.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Question and answer you refer to ([Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/16575)) are mine – so I can assure you they are still valid. As for the "built-in" backup: that's usually backing up to Google's servers, which works pretty well. What has mixed results, however, is the restore of that – which the user has very little means of controlling. It either works on first startup and configuring the Google account, or it works partially, or not at all.

I'd suggest you follow the procedure described there, and backup your contacts and messages separately. You can find some suitable apps [in my app lists](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_backup).

If your device were rooted, you could simply use *Titanium Backup* and be done with that, but I understand that's not always an option. If you have a backup device, I'd additionally suggest doing a "test restore" to that, to see that your crucial data can be restored properly. *WhatsApp* is a completely different case; though it has its own built-in backup, restore to a different device is tricky at best. If you don't mind (and using WhatsApp suggests as much), use it's Google Drive capabilities which should make things easier. Not that I have much experience with that (I wouldn't use WA unless threatened really hard).

Comment: Thanks. I backed up to SDcard manually from the settings.  Haven't found yet where it put the backup on the card :-)

Comment: I don't know 1) what you backed up and 2) what you used for that (from what settings?), so I cannot say anything for that. If you're sure it backed up to the card, check both of them if your device has both: internal card and external card :)

Comment: I added the settings path to the question.  I plan to add an answer myself once I figure this out.

Comment: Thanks! Might be interesting to add your device there as well, as I don't think that's a stock feature. Cannot verify, though, as I have no MM device here.